# classic asp not substituting the connection string

Tags: iis, asp-classic

We have a classic asp site that is running on windows server 2003. A typical call to make the connection takes the form:

`objConn.Open strConnectionString`

where strConnectionString has a value of **"IT"**

IT seems to be substituted for the actual connection string value which work's. This way of connecting is used throughout the site. I've now moved the site to Windows Server 2012 and now the site fails because it's not substituting the value. If I hard code the connection string value, then it works. I thought these might be values stored in IIS and the substitution takes place there, but looking in IIS on the Windows 2003 box, I cannot see any connection string values set. I also thought that these values may be Application level variables set at the start of the Application, but again I can find none. Does anybody have any thoughts on what's going on here.

I also have an ODBC Connection string called "IT" with the same connection string credentials as If I'd hardcoded the values and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok...Found the issue. When setting up the ODBC Connection I needed to have authentication set to Windows as opposed to SQL Server.